# OracleClient непонятные символы в конце каждой ячейки

Tags: c#, oracle, asp.net-core

Пишу приложение на asp.net core 2.0, бд - Oracle, ничего не подходит для подключению кроме стандартного System.Data.OracleClient;

После выполнения запроса в ответе почти в каждой ячейке на конце непонятный символ:

```
  OracleDataReader dataReader = command.ExecuteReader();
  string result = dataReader["LOGIN"].ToString();
```

Результаты типа Sergii Goriainov쳘, sgor⌴, DPå.

Как можно это исправить?

Comment: Проверьте (в режиме отладки, либо выведите в лог) что возвращает `dataReader["LOGIN"].ToString()`. Если там уже есть непонятный символ, то можно убрать скрин и лишний код.

Comment: `ничего не подходит для подключению кроме стандартного System.Data.OracleClient;` Это крайне странный выбор в 2017 году для нового проекта. Переходите на [`ManagedDataAccess`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Oracle.ManagedDataAccess/)

Comment: @defaultlocale К сожалению ManagedDataAccess все еще не совместим с .Net Core, хотя обещали к концу года установить поддержку. Поэтому это пока единственный рабочий вариант

Comment: Не знал об этом теперь понятно. По сути, может, глупый вопрос, но возвращаются ли нормальные данные (без символов) если запрос выполнить напрямую? Еще, возникает ли подобная проблема с другими запросами?

Comment: @defaultlocale Конечно,  sql developer достает данные валидные, и через ODAC тот же запрос достает чистые данные

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Разобрался, баг кодировки в самой [библиотеке](https://github.com/tonyrapozo/System.Data.OracleClient/issues/2).

Альтернатива Mono.Data.OracleClientCore с тем же багом [багом](https://github.com/LinqDan/oracleclientcore/issues/3).

Один из пользователей послал пул реквест с исправлением ошибки, работает. Пока не приняли вот ссылка на исходники -
https://github.com/LinqDan/oracleclientcore